# How to loop over System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CardDistro.Models.Transaction]

Tags: c#, linq

I can't get clear direction from Google search on this. I have a table called `transaction`, I want to group by `BatchID` and order by `descending` in respect to the foreign keys.

***Table Definition***

```
[TTransactionID]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[BatchID]             INT          NULL,
[CardID]              INT          NULL,
[UserID]              INT          NULL,
[TransactionDateTime] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
[TransactionStatus]   VARCHAR (11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TTransactionID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Cards] FOREIGN KEY ([CardID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cards] ([CardID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
```

***This is the code from my 5th Attempt***

```
        var TransactionList = db.Transactions
                                .GroupBy(x => new { x.BatchID })
                                .Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in TransactionList)
        {
            Response.Write( string.Format("[{0}] - {1}", index, item) );
            index++;
        }
```

When I run the above code. I get the following message on browser. I'm stuck here, what to do after this I have no idea.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SECardDistribution.Models.Transaction]
```

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: `foreach(var group in TransactionList) { foreach(var item in group) { ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the TransationList is sorted by BatchId ascending order then by CardId descending order.

```
var TransactionList = context.Trx
                .GroupBy(t => t.BatchId)    //group by BatchId
                .OrderBy(t => t.Key)        //order by BatchId
                .Select
                (g =>
                    //Create a new "Batch Group" anonymously where each batch contains the associated transactions
                    new
                    {
                        BatchId = g.Key,
                        BatchTransactions = g.Select(trx => new { Card = trx.Card, User = trx.User }).OrderByDescending(batchTrx => batchTrx.Card.CardId),    //order by CardId
                    }
                );
```

To loop through the sorted list, you can use nested foreach loop like this:

```
//Loop through the batch group in the sorted list
            foreach(var batchGroup in TransactionList)
            {
                foreach(var batchTrx in batchGroup.BatchTransactions)
                {
                    //You may access the properties of batchTrx like a normal object graph, example batchTrx.Card.CardId
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SelectMany` actually

```
var transactionList = db.Transactions.GroupBy(x => new { x.BatchID }).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are grouping the result in your LINQ query, you need to run two loops - one for groups and second for data in group.

```
var TransactionList = db.Transactions
                                .GroupBy(x => new { x.BatchID })
                                .Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();

foreach (var group in TransactionList)
{
   foreach(var item in group) 
   {
       // DO YOUR THINGS HERE...
   }
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var item in TransactionList.SelectMany(g => g)) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
// doing Select(x => x.ToList()) throws away group key!
var TransactionList = db.Transactions.GroupBy(x => x.BatchID).ToList();

foreach (var group in TransactionList)
{
    // now group variable is a ... well, group of transactions. :)
    // you can get its key and iterate over sub-collection of transactions in this group.
    Response.Write($"Group {group.Key}:\n");
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Response.Write($"    Transaction {item.TTransactionID}\n");
    }
}
```